# Show only current user's posts in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to show posts only that the current user has created on the frontend. That is, current, logged in user should be able to view only the posts he/she created across the website, including in the blog archive I want to display only current user's posts. And anyone with a link should be able to view the post too.
I tried the code below, but this also limits access to the pages which current user didn't create. And I need to limit access only to posts.

```
function exclude_other_users_posts( $query ) {
    if( !is_user_logged_in() ) {
        // guests cannot read private posts
        // and we exclude all public posts here
        // so guests can read nothing :-)
        $query->set( 'post_status', 'private' );
        $query->set( 'perm', 'readable' );
    } elseif( !current_user_can('read_others_posts') )
        $query->set( 'author', get_current_user_id() );
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'exclude_other_users_posts' );
```

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Author_Parameters

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this in the php files  that you want to display your posts.

```
global $current_user;
    get_currentuserinfo();
    $authorID = $current_user->ID;
        $args = array(
                  'post_type' => 'post',
                  'posts_per_page' => -1,
                  'author' => $authorID
                  );

        $wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
```

Then you can make your loop to show your posts.